# Error in insertion:connect ECONNREFUSED

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I'm trying to insert a value into my database, which is mydb and the table is login with 2 fields username and password. I'm using express.js and MySQL. The code of insert query is

```
exports.insert = function(req,res){
    client.query('insert into' +TABLE+ ' SET username=?,password=?' 
                , [req.body.txtUser,req.body.txtPassword]
                , &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;    
                  function(err,result){  
                     if(err){
                             console.log("error in insertion:"+ err.message);   
                             }
                     else{
                          console.log("query executed");
                          res.json("data inserted");
                          }
                      } 
                 );
             }
```

When I start the server it starts normal;y and show me the message:

> The Express server listening on port 3000 in development mode

But,  when I visit the signup page and insert the value and press submit the following error is generated

> error in insertion:connect ECONNREFUSED

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: It seems that you are not connecting to your MySQL server it may be wrong port or wrong host

Comment: please check my insert qurey is it correct or not please

Comment: The `ECONNREFUSED` error means that you are not connected to the MySQL server. This has nothing to do with your query.

Comment: If this code is intended to run in the client browser, somewhere in the js you will have to include the login/password for a DB account that has the rights to update the authentication tables.  Your JS code will allow anyone who looks to steal all the other users' passwords.  You don't really want to use this architecture.

Comment: @j0ntech but i ve included the mysql using npm wat i need to install to connect mysql and how cld i check if mysql is runing properly

Comment: You need to set up a MySQL server, an actual database. You have to connect to something, just installing the library isn't enough.

Comment: @j0ntech can u guide me how to set up a mysql server and a database :) please

Comment: There are any number of tutorials on the internet. For example, check this one: http://www.wikihow.com/Install-the-MySQL-Database-Server-on-Your-Windows-PC

Comment: ok thnx and can u tell me what shld i do after that?

Comment: @j0ntech ive installed the mysql server and create a db with name of my db ??

Comment: I'm not gonna take you through this using comments on Stackoverflow. Just use Google and you'll find a lot of tutorials and instructions.

Comment: @j0ntech ive created n m getting error of Table 'mydb.login' doesn't exist although i ve defined the table name and database aswell

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Node.js issue. You're unable to connect to your MySQL client in general.

You need to give access and permissions within MySQL to the username you're using to connect. Give access and then try to login manually to test this connection using a MySQL client or admin tool such as MySQL Admin or the command line `mysql` client. Remember, that in MySQL you have to setup for `localhost` as well as remote. I believe it still defaults to `localhost` only. e.g. you will need to explicitly set `admin@*` for other hostnames. Read the MySQL Manual [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html)

Once your client works, then your node.js client should work with the same username and settings.

Comment: thanku @Ehevutov the problem was solved acctualy i came from windows n worked n php with wamp which automaticaly install the mysql server but in ubuntu we have to install mysql server , which i didnt done so after install mysql server the problem was solved thanx